# Changing parent properties just inside the child element in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, parent

I am working with a WordPress theme having a background image, and background color of the body and the container are already white and they stretch till the footer. I want to give a gap inside the container so that I can have the background image to display in that div, by making its background color transparent, but I am getting this white color of container and body in between.

Is there any way I can change the background property of the parents (body and container) just for the area of that particular div element which I want to display transparent?
Is there any CSS selector to affect parent property referencing from the child element?

If not, kindly suggest how can I make it possible to display in the way I want?

Comment: > "Is there any CSS selector to affect parent property referencing from the child element". 
No

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it would help us understand the exact problem you're having?